# AccessViolationException on sp_session_player_load()

Tags: c#, naudio, libspotify

I'm trying to create a stream application based on Spotify's libspotify SDK.

To achieve this in C# I'm using the ohLibspotify bindings and wrapper. This is only a thin abstraction layer so most of it will be a 1:1 mapping to the libspotify SDK. To play the incoming PCM data I'm using the NAudio library.

Most of the times I can play the first track. Then when I load the second one I get a `AccessViolationException` whilst trying to call `sp_session_player_load()`. Also this sometimes happens the first time I try to play a track and sometimes it happens the third time.

This is the function I use to play a track.

```
public void playTrack(string track, string juke)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        var playable = Link.CreateFromString(string.Format("spotify:track:{0}", track)).AsTrack();

        if (playing)
        {
            player.Pause();
            App.Logic.spotify.sp_session.PlayerUnload();
        }

        buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat())
        {
            BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            DiscardOnBufferOverflow = false
        };

        var waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        while (!playable.IsLoaded())
        {
            waitEvent.WaitOne(30);
        }

        App.Logic.spotify.sp_session.PlayerLoad(playable);
        App.Logic.spotify.sp_session.PlayerPlay(true);

        player = new WaveOut();
        player.Init(buffer);
        player.Play();
        playing = true;
    })).Start();
}
```

The AccessViolationException occurs on line 6 of the following piece of code within the wrapper library.

```
    [DllImport("libspotify")]
    internal static extern SpotifyError sp_session_player_load(IntPtr @session, IntPtr @track);
    public void PlayerLoad(Track @track)
    {
        SpotifyError errorValue;
        errorValue = NativeMethods.sp_session_player_load(this._handle, track._handle);
        SpotifyMarshalling.CheckError(errorValue);
    }
```

The streaming callbacks:

```
        public override void GetAudioBufferStats(SpotifySession session, out AudioBufferStats stats)
        {
            stats = new AudioBufferStats()
            {
                samples = App.Logic.spotify.player.buffer.BufferedBytes / 2,
                stutter = 0
            };
        }

        public override int MusicDelivery(SpotifySession session, AudioFormat format, IntPtr frames, int num_frames) {
            int incoming_size = num_frames * format.channels * 2;
            try
            {
                if (incoming_size > sample_buffer.Length)
                {
                    short rendered_frames = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor((sample_buffer.Length / format.channels / 2d)));
                    short rendered_size = Convert.ToInt16(rendered_frames * format.channels * 2);
                    Marshal.Copy(frames, sample_buffer, 0, rendered_size);
                    App.Logic.spotify.player.buffer.AddSamples(sample_buffer, 0, rendered_size);
                    return rendered_frames;
                }
                else
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(frames, sample_buffer, 0, incoming_size);
                    App.Logic.spotify.player.buffer.AddSamples(sample_buffer, 0, incoming_size);
                    return num_frames;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose these errors. It could be: you're calling into libspotify on multiple threads - it is not thread-safe, so you must use locks to prevent two user threads ever running spotify code at the same time; you might not be handling spotify's ref-counting correctly, and accidentally decreasing a ref-count too early or forgetting to increment one somewhere it is necessary; you might be corrupting memory in the music callbacks that deal with native pointers; there might be a bug in ohLibSpotify or libspotify. Try working through that list in order.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! I've added the session callbacks used for streaming, maybe it'll help finding an answer. Furthermore I'm going to try the solutions you suggested,.

Comment: Indeed you were right, because I've done most of my development in Managed code it didn't occur to me that the problem might be threading. After implementing thread locking everything worked like a charm! I hope that I don't have to bother you again, thank you very much for your help @Weeble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Weeble said in his comment to my question. It is very hard to diagnose the possible source of an `AccessViolationException`. In my case it was threading, there were multiple threads accessing the Spotify session object at once.

If this could be your problem as well you might want to look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx). It talks about thread synchronization in C# and VB.Net. It's very easy really.

```
lock(sessionLock)
{
    App.Logic.spotify.sp_session.PlayerLoad(playable);
    App.Logic.spotify.sp_session.PlayerPlay(true);
}
```

The `sessionLock` object can be a simple instantiation of the `Object` type. Though it's not recommended to use any "actual" objects for this. In my case I did the following:

```
public class Player
{
    private object sessionLock = new object();

    // Rest of code with locks
}
```

This way you can lock the `sessionLock` object every time you want to access the, in this case, `SpotifySession` object. So that when thread 1 is loading a song and thread 2 wants to process the events at the same time, thread 2 will be blocked until the lock on `sessionLock` has been lifted.

As @Weeble suggested there are possibly some other things you might want to look into if threading is not the issue.

1. You might not be handling spotify's ref-counting correctly, and accidentally decreasing a ref-count too early or forgetting to increment one somewhere it is necessary.
2. You might be corrupting memory in the music callbacks that deal with native pointers.
3. There might be a bug in ohLibspotify or libspotify. If you think this is the case then go to the ohLibspotify [repo](https://github.com/openhome/ohLibSpotify) or the [openhome forum](http://forum.openhome.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=6) to report your issue.